# How to avoid jumping to d.ts in a monorepo with shared package

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I created a typescript monorepo using Yarn workspaces. One package "common" is shared by other packages.

Its package.json is configured like this:

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
```

Whenever I use the "go to definition" or cmd+click on a function in VSCode, it takes me to the d.ts file instead of the original typescript definition. This is really hurting my workflow.

Before I had main simply set to the TS source files, and that works with the jump to feature, but it is not deployable because some packages are built in the cloud during deployment and therefor the common package needs to be published with a regular javascript / NPM interface for it to work.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `typings` field. According to [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package), it is ignored when `files` are specified and just confuses IDEs...